# Using cURL, How can I fetch a numerical string which contains commas and spaces and convert such to a NON COMAFIED string

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, curl

Example: Google's Outstanding Shares are 670,000,000 and this value is collected in a txt file from Yahoo Finance API using the below script.

The issue is; that numbers WITH commas or spaces are near impossible for the text wizard and Excel to delimit when I pull this txt file into Excel to complete my work.

Ie the delimiter wants to break 670,000,000 into *three* separate values AND spread this across *three* columns which is a joke and renders my work futile.

Thus: I need the prospective script to bring all numerical strings that originally contained commas and spaces back to the txt file WITHOUT such. Ie no commas or no spaces.

So rather than 670,000,000 being brought into the txt file, I need 670000000 so that Excels antiquated delimiter may render the data into columns properly.

I have asked this question 4 times on here and each time the code provided by the super user has not worked.

```
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
  curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl&f=nsl1j2"
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
Done
```

Comment: In addition to the duplicates here, duplicated several times at Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/864339/ http://superuser.com/questions/865309/ http://superuser.com/questions/866651/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `sed` command after the `curl` command to replace commas inside numbers:

```
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
  curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl&f=nsl1j2"
  sed -i -E 's:([0-9]),([0-9]):\1\2:g' quotes.txt
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
Done
```

The result will look like this:

```
"Google Inc.","GOOG",508.08,   678365000
"Apple Inc.","AAPL",105.99,  5864839000
```

[image]

Comment: really appreciate the help. Will try this out and revert back. Thank you

Comment: I used the code you kindly issued and it makes no difference. The values do not arrive as you said in the result above minus the commma. I also get a note when I run the file saying sed: 1: "s:([0-9]),([0-9]):\1\2:g": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: I update my answer with an screenshot where you can see that the solution works. Seems that you are getting a error on `sed` command. The output of `sed --version` will help.

Comment: Hi there.  What are you suggesting that I do to the script.  Thanks

Comment: Execute the couple of commands I did in the screenshots and paste the results. Additionally, paste the output of `sed --version`.

Comment: paste the results into the code. I dont understand what you are saying. Your command is the same as before